# Не переключаются сцены в Unity WebGL

Tags: unity3d, webgl

Игра тестируется на Яндекс играх и в ней используется PluginYG. Я установил префаб YandexGame на каждую сцену. В Unity Editor все работало, но в билде под WebGL при переходе в другую сцену выходит ошибка
[image: скопировать не даёт]

В консоли пишет

```
Uncaught RuntimeError: null function or function signature mismatch
```

Скажите пожалуйста, как можно решить эту проблему или из за чего может быть вызвана эта ошибка?